# "How are they being supported?" vs "How are they supported?"

Tags: grammar

I was wondering whether which one of these two phrases would be correct?

> 1. How are they being supported?
> 2. How are they supported?

Comment: Both versions are syntactically valid - in many contexts they'd be (more or less) interchangeable, but sometimes one would be much more suitable than the other, and there *may* be contexts where only one would be "acceptable / correct / idiomatic". So you should give us a more precise explanation of the context you have in mind - as things stand, we don't even know if you're talking about a family in need of metaphorical financial support, or something like roof beam trusses on an architect's drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @fumblefingers points out, there is a slight difference between your two examples, thought they can often be used interchangably

> How are they **being** supported?

Tends to have a more *active* and *habitual* intent for a particular purpose where if the support were to end, whatever is being talked about would fail.

> How are the refugees ***being supported*** *(in the refugee camps)*?
>   The Red Cross is providing relief aid and shelter.
>
> How is the Red Cross ***being supported*** for refugee relief?  *(in particular)*
>   Private and public donations can be earmarked for emergency relief.
>
> How is the Red Cross ***supported***?  *(in general)*
>   Through donations of money, clothing, and supplies throughout the year.